# How to understand Algebraic mutiplicity in Geometric way

Tags: linear-algebra

Given vector space V in $\mathbb{F}^{n\times n}$,$A^{n\times n} \in V$

$\lambda_0$ is one of the eigenvalues of A.

There is $\dim{V}_{\lambda_0}\leq$ The mutiplicity of $\lambda_0$(which is the amount of the same $\lambda_0$ in the characteristic polynomial $\det{(A-\lambda I)}$)

I can undersand the algebraic proof given by the book.

But how to understand it in a geometric or visual way just like the plane in the 3 dimension space or something like it?